# How to make helm follow and show files as I type?

Tags: helm

My Emacs used to have the ability to display the help buffer of each function everytime I was scrolling through M-x function candidates. How to enable it again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `helm-follow-mode`.

According to Helm documentation (<kbd>C-h m</kbd> from inside an Helm buffer):

> When `helm-follow-mode` is on (C-c C-f
> to toggle it), moving up and down Helm session or updating the
> list of candidates will automatically execute the
> persistent-action as specified for the current source.

> If `helm-follow-mode-persistent` is non-nil, the state of the
> mode will be restored for the following Helm sessions.

> If you just want to follow candidates occasionally without
> enabling `helm-follow-mode`, you can use
> <kbd>C-down</kbd> or
> <kbd>C-up</kbd> instead.  Conversely, when
> `helm-follow-mode` is enabled, those commands go to previous/next
> line without executing the persistent action.

So the easiest way is to navigate with <kbd>C-down</kbd> or <kbd>C-up</kbd>.
<kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> allows you to toggle this behaviour and variable `helm-follow-mode-persistent` to make it persistent.

Comment: Thanks. I actually can't find helm-follow-mode in my system. I installed helm, but it doesn't show for some reason. In my init I actually had helm-follow-mode-persistent turned on. How can I install helm-follow-mode?

Comment: I meant to say, "In my init I actually have helm-follow-mode-persistent turned o but when I do M-x helm-follow-mode, there are no candidates. Also, C-c C-f does not seem to be binded to it."

Comment: You need to be in a helm session to use `C-c C-f`. Do `C-down` and `C-up` work in helm M-x?

Comment: Oh my god! You nailed it! Now I was in the helm session, and did C-c C-f and it worked. I did not know this. Regarding C-down and C-up, That's another thing, in my MAC if I do C-down, it shows the desktop. It's inbuilt mac behaviour, so I can't do C-down in Emacs. Not sure how I could enable this in Emacs.